# Atomic UPDATE and SELECT of Cassandra counter table

Tags: cassandra, nosql, atomic

I need help/advices according to following issue:

I have a counter table which gets incremented by asynchronous processes. Each process needs the new value after the incrementation update. But the two operations (UPDATE and SELECT) aren't atomic. So, it's possible that a second process did a further incrementation in the meantime. The result is a wrong counter value in the SELECT result of the first process (`counter + 2` instead of `counter + 1`). How can I manage this issue?

It would be nice if I could combine UPDATE and SELECT into one atomic transaction. In 2014 somebody already asked for this feature. But it seems, that it won't be implemented:

http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/145xexrr0f/retrieve-counter-value-after-update

Comment: You can accomplish this with Cassandra but its horribly slow and kinda the wrong solution. Have you considered something like a database with full transactions or something like redis?

Comment: Agreed. Read-after-write should a red flag in your mind when working with Cassandra. A secondary datastore (like Redis) for this operation might be much better suited if your application cannot tolerate the consistency offered.

Comment: In my case I'm bound to Cassandra. I need this counter value as a unique value in another table (is a primary key) (for versioning). If two processes write their data to this table but with the same counter value then one entry gets lost. How can I UPDATE-and-SELECT with Cassandra?

Comment: You might try using a lightweight transaction on the insert into the secondary table. An `IF NOT EXISTS` should achieve what you are after (with additional fallback logic in your app). But, again, be careful here. I've run into lots of trouble trying to get fancy with Cassandra data models in this way.

Comment: Thanks Matt! This would help so far: 1. Increment and obtain counter 2. ``INSERT IF NOT EXISTS`` 3. Check success via ``result.wasModified()`` 4. Restart everything if insertion failed